# Python subprocess not executing program correctly

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a Fortran program in a shell from Python.
I'm using `subprocess` to call the Fortran program and pass arguments (two input files are required). This is how I do it:

```
COMMAND = '/path/to/FORTRAN/program << !\n' + INPUT_FILE1 + '\n' + INPUT_FILE2 +'\n!'
return = subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```

Unfortunately, the Fortran program exits with:

```
? FORTRAN Runtime Error:
? Attempt to read past end of file
? READ(UNIT=22,...
```

This is **not** an issue with the input files or the Fortran program. When I execute this in my shell:

```
$>/path/to/FORTRAN/program << !
>INPUT_FILE1
>INPUT_FILE2
>!
```

everything works as expected (no `Attempt to read past end of file`).

I don't have access to the Fortran source, so I cannot check what is going on in there. I think it has to do with the way I'm calling the program through `subprocess` - I just can't figure out what.

I'm using Python 2.6.6.

Quick explanation: The Fortran program will prompt for two input files, but it doesn't recognize them as command-line options (they cannot be provided with the call to the program). If you want to run it from - say a shell script (batch mode) - you need to capture the return command to execute the command, but also provide the two files. The `<< !` opens a "list" for lack of a better term. The following commands are handed to the program which waits with its execution until `!` is typed.

I have used this approach multiple times successfully (different Fortran code), and with this one, using a [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) script (not Python).

Comment: I don't know enough about running FORTRAN from a terminal - what's the significance of `<<`?  Is that reading from `stdin` or otherwise?  Perhaps the problem is that you're submitting the input files as arguments, but it expected a buffer it's going to parse.  Hard to say without more info about the program in question.

Comment: I tried to reproduce by calling a small program that dumps its stdin, and both the command-line and `subprocess` work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `"\r\n"` (tty newline):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["/path/to/FORTRAN/program"], stdin=PIPE,
          bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
p.communicate("INPUT_FILE1\r\nINPUT_FILE2")
rc = p.returncode
```

with/without `"\r\n"` at the end.

Comment: this worked, with a slight modification: I used ``p.communicate("INPUT_FILE1\nINPUT_FILE2")`` without the ``\r``. What is the difference between the ``communicate`` and the ``stdin.write``, as suggested by @Armin-Rigo? Or is this rather a different question ...

Comment: In this case it should be equivalent to `.stdin.close(); .wait()`. The difference might be in the initial `.write()` part.

Comment: Though [looking at the source I don't see any difference](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/subprocess.py#l673) except `bufsize=1` (line-buffered) and `close_fds=True` (the latter should be default on posix)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's caused by the shell invoked with `shell=True`, if that doesn't invoke `bash` on your system.  You can avoid depending on the extended shell syntax `<<`, and instead build the whole call on your own, as in:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/FORTRAN/program"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.stdin.write('123\n')
time.sleep(0.1)    # hack, following LAK's suggestion
popen.stdin.write('456\n')
popen.stdin.close()
result = popen.wait()
```

Comment: I've tried your updated proposal - and played with the ``sleep`` command a little - without success. For now I fixed it by writing the command to a shell script and executing that from Python. Maybe a bit convoluted, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had what may have been a similar problem a while back, and the solution turned out to be adding a small pause.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740887/controlling-puttygen-with-popen) and see whether that technique helps.